# UWP Where did my Bullet Intersect an Image on Canvas (coordinates relative to image)

Tags: image, canvas, uwp, 2d, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to develop a 2D game using a canvas. Right now I have a shooter and a target. The shooter fires a bullet image. Every frame, I check to see if the bullet is inside the bounds of the target. If it is, I need to know where the bullet hit the target, relative to the Target upper left. So if my target is in the center of my canvas and the target is 100 X wide by 100 Y tall and I hit bottom center, I want it to return 50,100.

```js
private void CannonBulletTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (m_bFiredShot)
    {
        if (m_dCannonBulletTop > 0)
        {
            m_dCannonBulletTop = m_dCannonBulletTop - m_dCannonBulletStepSize;
            CannonBullet.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, m_dCannonBulletTop);
            Windows.Foundation.Point point = new Windows.Foundation.Point(m_dCannonBulletLeft, m_dCannonBulletTop);
            if (BulletInsideBunker(Bunker1))
            {
                if (GetPixelColors(Bunker1, m_Wb1))
                {
                    KillCannonBullet();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            KillCannonBullet();
        }
    }
}

private bool BulletInsideBunker(Image bunker)
{
    bool ret = false;
    m_dBunkerHeight = Bunker1.ActualHeight;
    double BunkerLeft = (double)bunker.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);

    if (m_dCannonBulletTop > m_dBunkerTop && m_dCannonBulletTop < m_dBunkerTop + m_dBunkerHeight)
    {
        if (m_dCannonBulletLeft - m_dCannonBulletWidth >= BunkerLeft && m_dCannonBulletLeft <= BunkerLeft + m_dBunkerWidth)
        {
            ret = true;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

private bool GetPixelColors(Image Bunker, WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    bool ret = false;
    double BunkerLeft = (double)Bunker.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
    double BunkerTop = (double)Bunker.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);           

    double imageX = m_dCannonBulletLeft - BunkerLeft;
    double imageY = m_dCannonBulletTop - BunkerTop;

    for (double y = imageY; y < imageY + m_dCannonBulletHeight; y++)
    {
        int iY = (int)y;
        for (double x = imageX; x < imageX + m_dCannonBulletWidth; x++)
        {
            int iX = (int)x;
            Windows.UI.Color color = wb.GetPixel(iX, iY);

            if (color.G == 253)
            {
                wb.SetPixel(iX, iY, Colors.Black);
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }
    Bunker.Source = wb;
    return ret;
}
```

I am having trouble down in GetPixelColor. I am trying to calculate where the bullet hit the Bunker. But when I am moving through the double y and double x for loops, the wrong pixels in the target are being painted black. They are up and to the left significantly if I shoot the right side of the image. As I move further to the left, the X gets a little more accurate, but the Y is still way off.

How can I accurately translate from Canvas coordinates to Image coordinates? Does the resolution of my image have anything to do with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the answer to this since yesterday. I finally found the answer here [X,Y coordinates for WriteableBitmap and GestureListener_Tap do not match - Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659596/x-y-coordinates-for-writeablebitmap-and-gesturelistener-tap-do-not-match-windo)
after I posted this.

Here is my new method:

```js
private bool GetPixelColors(Image Bunker, WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    bool ret = false;
    double BunkerLeft = (double)Bunker.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
    double BunkerTop = (double)Bunker.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);

    int imageX = (int)m_dCannonBulletLeft - (int)BunkerLeft;
    int imageY = (int)m_dCannonBulletTop - (int)BunkerTop;

    int TransformedY = yCoordinateToPixel(imageY, Bunker, wb);
    int TransformedX = xCoordinateToPixel(imageX, Bunker, wb);

    for (int y = TransformedY - 2; y < TransformedY + (int)m_dCannonBulletHeight + 2; y++)
    {
        for (int x = TransformedX; x < TransformedX + (int)m_dCannonBulletWidth; x++)
        {
            Windows.UI.Color color = wb.GetPixel(x, y);

            if (color.G == 253)
            {
                wb.SetPixel(x, y, Colors.Black);
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }
    Bunker.Source = wb;
    return ret;
}

private int xCoordinateToPixel(int coordinate, Image Bunker, WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    double x;
    x = wb.PixelWidth / Bunker.ActualWidth * coordinate;
    return Convert.ToInt32(x);
}

private int yCoordinateToPixel(int coordinate, Image Bunker, WriteableBitmap wb)
{
    double y;
    y = wb.PixelHeight / Bunker.ActualHeight * coordinate;
    return Convert.ToInt32(y);
}
```